# PHP - redirecting all pages to home page.

Tags: php, localhost, opencart

I used php opencart for e-commerce website. Works everything fine when configured with apache on AWS server. I wanted to set it up locally and I stared the server using the command

```
php -S :8001
```

Home page is loading fine. If i click on any link url is changing but home page is only coming all the time. For example http://localhost:8001/ and http://localhost:8001/entertainment-leisure both are giving same response.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out whats the issue here. PHP local server cannot access .htaccess file. Hence it cannot rewrite urls. Open cart is using .htaccess to rewrite urls. So for every page it will redirect to home page. I configured with apache in local and it worked fine for me. Point to be noted PHP local server will not have full options without apache.

Comment: mod_rewrite is an apache extension, so.. yeah, it's not going to work without apache

Answer (score 0):

you can deactivate "SEO URL" in Admin->System->Settings->Server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to activate "SEO URL" in Admin->System->Settings->Server. or you can use index.php?route= variable in URL to run other pages.
Something like this:

> http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/category&path=18